# What does ZED mean?

Tags: animation, shortcut

I was watching a tutorial but then he said to press "ZED" and i don't know what it means.

[This was the video i was watching](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pj5Ni-RmSlo) and in minute 3:50 he says "ZED"

Answer (score 3):

He said G Z ....and meant the letters G and Z :)

although check this:

https://www.google.com/search?q=pronounce+z&oq=pronounce+z&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512j0i22i30l8.8552j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=_bDR0Ye5viYz27w_E5IvoDA25

it is a difference between british and american english.